# MySQL Workbench: Unable to CREATE/UPDATE table from valid SELECT

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have an SQL SELECT statement of the form:

```
SELECT a.date, a.count FROM (
  SELECT d.date, x.count + y.count - z.count AS count
  FROM date_table d
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date, count FROM caluculated_table_x
  ) x ON d.date = x.date 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date, count caluculated_table_y
  ) y ON d.date = y.date 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date, count caluculated_table_z
  ) z ON d.date = z.date
) a ON a.date = d.date;
```

The SELECT works just fine, taking roughly 10s to complete. However, when I try to use it in a CREATE TABLE/UPDATE/INSERT INTO statement, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE count_summary
SELECT...;
```

I get "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query" after 600s. Any idea what might be causing this issue or how I might diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is this the actual query you use or you simplified it to post here? How many rows are returned?

Comment: Simplified. The calculated tables join two or three tables a piece to produce counts of specific actions on a given day, joining to a specified list of dates from **date_table**. The query produces 1164 rows. I have tried update/inserting with other more basic tables, with similar data, and that worked just fine.

Comment: Is the same behaviour observed if you run it in 2 statements? `CREATE TABLE t (<columns>); INSERT INTO t SELECT ...;` instead of one?

Comment: Correct. It runs all command up until the CREATE statement, and then stalls exactly as the `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ... ;`

Comment: I asked wha happens if you run two statements. One CREATE and one INSERT.

Comment: Yes, the same behavior occurs. I meant to say it performs the CREATE, then stalls at the INSERT.

Comment: The query is flawed -- `a.date = d.date` cannot work because `d.date` is not visible outside there.